# jQuery how to switch li position inside of ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an unordered list with bunch of li's in it.

```
<ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
    <li>item 5</li>
    <li>item 6</li>
</ul>
```

and what I'd like to achieve is, if I click on `<li>item 2</li>` it would switch index with `<li>item 1</li>` another words item 2 becomes item 1 and if I click new item 2 which was previously item 1, it has to switch again and keep looping continuously as long as item 2 is clicked. Same should be true for 3,4 and 5,6.

Comment: first switch is easy to understand... the others aren't as clear...they always go to top  and top goes to their position? ALso what have you tried? You should be showing the code you have used to attempt to solve this yourself and we help fix any issues

Comment: items 3 and 4 should switch positions between them and same for 5 and 6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the switching to occur *ONLY* between paired items (i.e. 1-2, 3-4, 5-6 and so on)

*Working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/drcnb7he/4/)*

```
$('ul li').on('click', function(e){
    var index = $(this).index();  // Index of clicked item
    var temp = $(this).html();    // Contents of clicked item
    var partner;                  // The paired element

    if((index+1) % 2 == 0) { // Even
        partner = $(this).parent().find('li').get(index-1);
    }else { // Odd
        partner = $(this).parent().find('li').get(index+1);
    }

    // Put this in a try/catch to not throw errors for unmatched list items
    // (i.e. a list with 9 items, and then clicking on the 9th)
    try{
        $(this).html(partner.innerHTML);
        $(partner).html(temp);
    }catch(e) {}
});
```

What this does is:

1. Get the index and contents of the clicked item
2. Determine if clicked is odd or even
3. Assign the appropriate partner element
4. Swap contents (*if* partner element exists)

Follow the same pattern to switch whichever items you want

Comment: this is clean and elegant code sir.  The usage of the `modulus` and `try` `catch` methods are great exposures.

Comment: @AlexanderDixon thanks. I'm sure someone will have a 2-line solution and say otherwise, but it gets the job done good enough. Upvotes help too, as it's now a race to the top!

Answer (score 1):

Your description isn't very clear, and like charlietfl said you should provide any code where you attempted to do this not just the html as you tagged this as javascript, anyways you could try something like this:

```
$("ul").on( "click", "li" , function(){
    var text = $(this).text();
  $(this).remove();
  $("ul").prepend("<li>"+text+"</li>");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution using `insertBefore()` and `insertAfter()`

```
 // add attributes to elements for pairing
$('li').each(function(i) {
  var partner = i % 2 == 0 ? i + 1 : i - 1
  $(this).attr({ id: i,'data-index': i,'data-partner': partner})
}).click(function() {
  var $el = $(this), 
      currIdx = $el.index(),      
      origIdx = $el.data('index'),
      partnerIdx = $el.data('partner'),   
      dir;
  if (currIdx != origIdx) {
    dir = partnerIdx > origIdx ? 'After' : 'Before'
  } else {
    dir = partnerIdx > origIdx ? 'Before' : 'After'
  } 
  $('#' + partnerIdx)['insert' + dir](this)
});
```

If partner not available jQuery selector at the end will fail quietly

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/nw7xryzg/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: a very interesting  usage of insertAfter and insertBefore. Thanks so much

Comment: @gaetanoM people forget sometimes that all the chain methods are just object properties.

Answer (score 0):

lol is id of ul

```
 $("#lol li:odd").click(function()
        {
            var $preSibiling = $(this).prev(),
                prevValue = $preSibiling.text(),
                presentValue = this.innerText;
            $preSibiling.text(presentValue);
            this.innerText = prevValue;

        })
```